Widget to call a Python Script
I have a Python script on my Ubuntu box that I usually call from the Terminal. It'll be great to have a desktop widget instead to call it.
The script accepts 3 parameters, which could be radio buttons, checkboxes or something similar. Clicking some sort of a Submit button on the widget would call the script with the relevant parameters.
Is this possible? Thank you.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? You may want to look at Python GUI coding tools.

Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I'm new to widgets, and was hoping there's something out of the box like Screenlets or Gdesklets that can be used..

from tkinter import *

This question is similar to: Make a Python program executable from its icon. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
